# "Snap" tables together via Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to "snap" one table to the bottom of another, while retaining `table-bordered` features (e.g. rounded edges).

Desired effect showing the two tables "snapping" together:

[image: Desired effect]

The rounded corners aren't in shot, but you get the idea.

Comment: Are you not able to simply set the colspan of columns to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: I did consider that, but unfortunately `colspan` isn't the desired effect in this case. If it were a set-width "brickwork" design it probably would, but my column widths are quite varied in size. Plus it can be a pain having to adjust the `colspan` each time, and can be quite tedious if the table gets really big!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not such a thing available in TB by default as far as I know, but nothing prevents you from writing your own css, and overwriting the TB styles. That is the beauty of css!

If you inspect the code with something like Chrome Inspector, it becomes very easy to copy the applied TB styles, and alter them to your wishes. That is exactly what I did and this is what I came up with (unprefixed!):

```
table.table-snap {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-bottom-width: 0;
}
table.table-bordered.table-snap:last-child {
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.table-bordered.table-snap > thead > tr > th, 
.table-bordered.table-snap > tbody > tr > td, 
.table-bordered.table-snap > tfoot > tr > td, 
.table-bordered.table-snap {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
}
.table-bordered.table-snap:first-child thead:first-child tr:first-child > th:first-child, 
.table-bordered.table-snap:first-child tbody:first-child tr:first-child > td:first-child, 
.table-bordered.table-snap:first-child tbody:first-child tr:first-child > th:first-child,
.table-bordered.table-snap:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 4px !important;
}
.table-bordered.table-snap:first-child thead:first-child tr:first-child > th:last-child, 
.table-bordered.table-snap:first-child tbody:first-child tr:first-child > td:last-child, 
.table-bordered.table-snap:first-child tbody:first-child tr:first-child > th:last-child,
.table-bordered.table-snap:first-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 4px !important;
}
.table-bordered.table-snap:last-child thead:last-child tr:last-child > th:first-child, 
.table-bordered.table-snap:last-child tbody:last-child tr:last-child > td:first-child, 
.table-bordered.table-snap:last-child tbody:last-child tr:last-child > th:first-child,
.table-bordered.table-snap:last-child {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px !important;
}
.table-bordered.table-snap:last-child thead:last-child tr:last-child > th:last-child, 
.table-bordered.table-snap:last-child tbody:last-child tr:last-child > td:last-child, 
.table-bordered.table-snap:last-child tbody:last-child tr:last-child > th:last-child,
.table-bordered.table-snap:last-child {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px !important;
}
```

All you need to do now is apply the `.table-snap` class to every table you want to 'snap' to its siblings, and you should get the result you wanted: http://jsfiddle.net/ycTj8/

Comment: Absolutely fantastic! Thank you.